# Touch controls working for iOS 7,6,5... but not for iOS 8

Tags: ios, opengl-es, touch, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I developed a OpenGL ES game several years ago and works well until now: I have downloaded Xcode 6 and iOS 8 in my iPad 3, and touch control (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded) only detect a square of 768x768 points, instead of 1024x768.

A margin of 256 points (1024-768) not respond to pulsations.

The game is in landscape mode.

It seems as if the touch control think that iPad is in portrait mode instead of landscape mode. Visually it is in landscape.

Looks like a bug in iOS 8.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have this problem too, although testing on an iPhone 6 the restricted area is 640x640. It only seems to affect touchesBegan touches here - once the touch transitions to touchesMoved the x coordinates are returned correctly.

Comment: I have same problem, iPhone 6, OpenGL ES, frame bounds is 736x414 landscape mode. touchesBegan give me X no more than 414, but Y returned correctly. touchesMoved work fine, get X range from 0 to 736.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out if anyone is still dealing with this - it looks like iOS 8 causes some problems when adding a UIView directly to the window in the app delegate. I had to create a UIViewController, add the UIView to that, and then make it the root view controller.